# Microsoft Access Form To Query for Multi Value Field

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to write an Microsoft Access query from a form with a multi value field being the criteria. The field I am trying to use is called `Population` and the field is represented in my database as a List Box that allows multiple values and it is in the Building table.  The values it allows are the following:

```
"Singles";"Familes";"Families with Children";"Youth/Young Adults";"Veterans";
```

The form that I am creating is called `HousingSearch`.

I am trying to create a form which uses this field, so someone could use the list box and check off the values they want and click on the button which would open a query.  I know having done this with single value fields the criteria in the query looks something like

```
[forms]![HousingSearch]![Building]![Population]
```

but if you try the same thing for a multi value field nothing is returned for the query.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided it seems that the phrase [Forms]![HousingSearch]![Building]![Population] are combining a request that starts with a form and then jumps to a table.

You are asking access to find data in a form but the information you're most likely trying to access is in a table.  I don't quite understand what you're end result is but I think that you most likely want to refer to your information this way [Building]![Population].  Referring to your data this way makes access look at the table of [Building] and then into the field of [Population].

It's been a while since you posted, if you haven't cleared things up already I hope this helps.